# multiple input types ("either / or") for option in python click

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-click

Is it possible to specify two input types for a `click.option`, one of which the supplied value has to be in?

In a normal python function with typing, I'd declare it like so:

```py
from typing import Union

def fun(x: Union[int, str]):
    if isinstance(x, str):
        x = int(x)
    return x**2
```

so `x` should be either an `int` or `str`.

In `click` I want to achieve the same thing, just with the addition that the script fails when the input type isn't in the defined ones.

I've tried

```py
@click.option('-x', type=(click.INT, click.STRING))
```

but that seems to be only for occasions with multiple arguments.

Comment: if you want it to convert `string` to `int` then maybe simply use `int(variable)` without checking type. If you use `int(integer_number)` then you get the same integer number. If you use `int(string_number)` then you get value converted to integer number.

Comment: @furas this is just a toy example - in the real application, the two types would be a file or the already parsed contents of the file

Comment: I don't use ``click` and I don't know how you want to recognize `file` and `context` - for `Python` both would be only strings. I would rather use two different variables for this - ie. `-f` for `file` and `-t` for `text/content` - first function (assigned to `-f`) would load file and run second function (assigned to `-t`).